# Exercise: Upper bound for $\;\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^n)\;$ function

Tags: matrices, analysis, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

> Let $\;f \in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^n;\mathbb R)\;$ a non-negative function which vanishes on a finite set $\;A \subset \mathbb R^n\;$ and assume that
>   the matrix $\;\frac{{\partial}^2 f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\;$
>   is positive definite for $\;a \in A$. Prove that
>   there exist $\;c \gt 0\;$ and $\;r \gt 0\;$ such that: $\;f(x) \le
>  c{\vert x-a \vert}^2\;$ , for $\;\vert x-a \vert \le r\;$.

**My approach:**

By Taylor expansion for $\;f\;$ I get: $\;f(x)=f(a)+ \nabla f(a)(x-a)\;+\;\frac{1}{2} \left\langle {\partial}^2 f(a) (x-a), (x-a)\right\rangle\;+o({\vert x-a \vert}^2)\;=\;\frac{1}{2} \left\langle {\partial}^2 f(a) (x-a), (x-a)\right\rangle\;+o({\vert x-a \vert}^2)\;$

because $f(a)=0\;\;\forall a \in A\;$ and $\; \nabla f(a)=0\;$ since the matrix $\;\frac{{\partial}^2 f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\;$ is positive definite.

Furthermore, I know that all the eigenvalues of $\;\frac{{\partial}^2 f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\;$ are positive so I can write: $\;0\lt λ_1 \le λ_2 \le \dots \le λ_n\;$.

I asked, at this point, my professor for a hint which I give below:

$\;\frac{1}{2} \left\langle {\partial}^2 f(a) (x-a), (x-a)\right\rangle\; \le λ_n {\vert x-a \vert}^2 \;$.

I understand that $\frac{1}{2} \left\langle {\partial}^2 f(a) (x-a), (x-a)\right\rangle\; \le \vert {\partial}^2 f(a) \vert \left\langle (x-a), (x-a)\right\rangle\;= \vert {\partial}^2 f(a) \vert {\vert x-a \vert}^2 \; $ but it's unclear to me why $\;\vert {\partial}^2 f(a) \vert \le λ_n\;$.

**Questions:**

1. Why does $\;\vert {\partial}^2 f(a) \vert \le λ_n\;$ hold?
2. Could somebody claim somehow that $\;\vert {\partial}^2 f(a) \vert \ge λ_1\;$ holds?

I'm not very familiar with norm of matrices so it may be quite elementary what I'm missing. I would appreciate any help because I'm stuck!

Thanks in advanvce!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote $H=\partial^2 f$ and $v=x-a$. Your question why (I assume you are talking about the spectral norm) $\|H\|\le\lambda_{\max}$ is true can be answered as, in fact,
$$
\|H\|=\lambda_{\max}
$$
for [Hermitian matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix). It can be proved via unitary diagonalisation of Hermitian matrix
$$
H=UDU^*
$$
where $D=\text{diag}\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and $U$ is unitary, because $\|H\|=\|D\|=\lambda_{\max}$ (the spectral norm is unitary invariant and the norm of the diagonal matrix is an easy exercise).

It makes the answer to your second question trivial as $\|H\|=\lambda_{\max}\ge\lambda_{\min}$. What is more interesting is to take a bit better estimations for
$$
\langle Hv,v\rangle.
$$ 
Using the property of [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) it is easy to conclude that
$$
\lambda_{\min}\|v\|^2\le\langle Hv,v\rangle\le\lambda_{\max}\|v\|^2,
$$
which fits your needs better.

Comment: First of all I'd like to thank you for your quick answer. So my professor used the property of Rayleigh quotient in order to take this upper bound, right? The fact that the given matrix is symmetric and positive definite implies it's also Hermitian and this is why the property you mentioned is valid here. Is my argument right? I want to be sure that I fully understood it..

Comment: Yes, that's correct - the matrix of second derivatives for $C^2$ function is symmetric (which for real matrices is the same as Hermitian). Note that you need the Rayleigh estimation with $\lambda_{\min}$ to get rid of the remainder $o(\|v\|^2)$.

Comment: @Α.Γ. Thanks again for your time!!!

Comment: @kaithkolesidou You are welcome :)

Comment: @Α.Γ. Wait, if I write $\;\frac{1}{2} \left\langle {\partial}^2 f(a) (x-a), (x-a)\right\rangle\;+o({\vert x-a \vert}^2)\; \le \lambda_{\max}\|x-a\|^2\;+o({\vert x-a \vert}^2)\;=\;{\vert \vert x-a \vert \vert}^2 (\lambda_{\max}\ + \frac{o({\vert x-a \vert}^2)}{{\vert \vert x-a \vert \vert}^2})\;$ then I can get rid of the remainder letting $\;x \to a\;$. Why is the $\;\lambda_{\min}\;$ estimation needed?

Comment: @kaithkolesidou Sorry, you are right, I did not notice that it was only $\le$ that you needed.

Comment: @Α.Γ. Oh, ok then.. You've been very helpful! Good night! :)